# Networking - sending and receiving data

Tags: networking, encoding, server, ip

This could not be the right place, as it's not about pure programming;
nevertheless, as a simple web developer I find myself quite 
ignorant on the subject of networking(Wikipedia usually mix 
different subjects on the matter), and I feel as it is a "must" to know.
I sort of have an image of what happens when you write google.com
on your browser, and I don't know the whole process(I have a modem,
 a router and a few computers connected to it. let's use my case for an example):

```
You write characters into chrome -> 
there is some character encoding done to translate the address(ASCII or else) -> 
DNS does something, not sure -> 
your router receives a digital request from a computer's internet cable/WIFI, it saves the internal IPV4 address of     
the sender in order to know to which computer to respond back. it sends the digital data to the modem -> 
your modem receives digital data, and translates it from digital to analog ->
now your network provider does some work - > 
the google server receives a request from an IP address - > 
not sure how the google server handles the data, nevertheless it sends back data ->
service provider - > router gets translated digital data from the modem and remembers who sent the request, and sends it to the right person.
```

in order to optimize a web server or maybe to write a better code which involves networking, perhaps each beginner(such as myself) needs to understand this first? Thank you for your time.
EDIT: I did read wikipedia's OSI model, though it's not quite as helpful as I thought it would.

Comment: Search for `OSI model` on the Internet.

Comment: I searched WIKIPEDIA's OSI model - they didn't get into it enough. thanks anyhow.

Comment: You need to go beyond the definition sites and get into some of the hundreds of sites which explain it in depth, such as http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0131014684/samplechapter/0131014684_ch02.pdf. You need to clearly understand the layer model of networking first, then you can fill in the blanks on some of your questions.

Comment: as I understand the OSI model is 7 levels, and you gave me 20-page link only on layer 2, 3 and 4? I am looking for a chronological explanation - for instance, like my example above, what happens when you write an address until you get the data back from the server. Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: It was an example, and it does discuss all the layers. It gives you what happens from your browser in the "_Putting All the Layers Together_" section.

Answer (score 0):

i will try to explain the idea, although its may be much ,more complicate - it depends on how deep you want to go ...

1. you write "www.stackoverflow.com"
2. your OS will try to resolve the www.stackoverflow.com to an IP address
3. since your OS probably cant, it needs to ask a DNS server
4. assuming you use an external DNS ( say IP=5.5.5.5 and your IP=10.10.10.10 which is on a different networks ), your OS will check if it knows how to reach 5.5.5.5
5. a default route 0.0.0.0/0 exists on your PC (this is also known as 'default-gw' which includes ALL internet, it points to your local router
6. an IP packet will be sent to the router MAC address with the DNS IP address in the destination
7. your router will probably change your private IP address to its own public IP address and will sends it to the ISP
8. ISP will route it to the internet until it reaches 5.5.5.5 which is the DNS
9. DNS will reply back resolving stackoverflow.com to an IP address
10. your PC now knows how to send packets to stackoverflow.com
11. packet will be sent to stackoverflow ip address (104.16.36.249) to port 80 (http)
12. stackoverflow web server listen to requests on port 80
13. once a packet arrives it will generate a response packet
14. it will send it back to you exactly in the same way

all that traffic can be seen with a network capture utility like wireshark, u can use those commands (windows) to verify...

> ping stackoverflow.com
>
> netstat -rn
>
> ipconfig
>
> nslookup
>
> tracert -d